# Manual approval / rejection of user registration by admin using Firebase

Tags: firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

Currently I'm designing an application in Swift 3.0 that will be used by a small group up to 100 users.

Users will register through a simple registration form using email id and password but Admin will have to approve or reject the user registration request manually.

Workflow I can think of is if a user register, admin will get some notification or email that a new user registration request is there and then when admin approve or rejects the user registration request and user  will get a email (that his registration is approved or rejected).

Is it possible with Firebase, I have tried reading Firebase documents but cannot find anything that can be helpful in this case.

Any help or ideas are very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible, you have to add a field to your user node name it as example `approved` by default 0, when a new user is added to your database the admin receive a notification and check the registration if accepted change the value to of `approved` to 1 else delete the user data

Comment: Thanks for your reply, It looks like it can solve the issue. But I am still  a bit lost as I am really new to swift, it will be great if you can add more details to your answer. As of now in firebase a new user with all the attributes is created when he fills the registration form and then clicks "register".

Comment: sorry i'm an android developer i have no idea about swift

Comment: It will also be great, if u can some code in java here, atleast  I will be able to get a clear idea :).Many Thanks.