# Google firebase manual database post approval

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

is there a way to manual approve the posts that is being posted to the firebase database through the rules?

the current rule is like this:

```
{

  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

**what I meant is to  allow the users to post from into database, but I as an admin control the posts either approve or reject the post from firebase console, is that possible through the rules?**

like this [Manual approval / rejection of user registration by admin using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931874/manual-approval-rejection-of-user-registration-by-admin-using-firebase/49718608?noredirect=1#comment86450233_49718608)

Comment: Please elaborate your question.

Comment: what I meant is to  allow the users to post from into database, but I as an admin control the posts either approve or reject the post from firebase console, is that possible through the rules?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing built into Firebase for such an approval queue, but you could definitely build it into your app on top of Firebase.

What you essentially do is create a so-called moderation queue, that the users post to. So you end up with two top-level nodes:

```
posts
  post1: ...
  post2: ...
  post3: ...
pending
  post4: ...
  post5: ...
```

The users of your regular app only see the data from `/posts`.

Then you create a separate app for your moderators, and that app shows the posts in the moderation queue (`/pending` above) and gives them the option to approve or reject them. If they approve the post, it is added to the actual list of postings that users of the regular app see.

If the app for your moderators is running in a trusted environment, you could consider using the Admin SDK, which ignores the security rules and always has full access to your database. In that case your rules could be as simple as:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      ".read": true
    },
    "pending": {
      "$postid": {
          ".write": "!data.exists"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This allows anyone to read the posts, but only administrators can write them. On the other hand, anyone can write to the moderator queue (as long as they're not overwriting existing data), but only administrators can read from there.

Comment: that's Good Answer!, but firebase is allow me to have only one Database for free!

Comment: @Steven This example only uses a single database.